# Error trying to merge 2 variables into one

Tags: powershell

I have a problem when I try to merge 2 variables into one.
Example:

```
$MyA = @{
   foo = 1..10
   bar = 2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20
   }
 $MyB = @{
   foo = 1..30
   bar = ""
   }

Foreach ($_ in $MyA) {Where $MyB.foo -eq $_.foo;  $MyB.bar = $_.bar}
```

What I want to do is: Insert $MyA.bar into $MyB.bar where the property foo matches....
But it ends up with this error message:
Where-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Object[]'.

What I want to end up with is something like this:

```
$MyB
foo bar
--------
1   2
2   4
```

etc. until foo is grater than 10 then bar should be empty
Please help!

Comment: Can you describe the intended "merged object"? What would the value of `bar` look like?

Comment: [1] this >>> `$MyB.foo` <<< will be a collection, not one value. ///// [2] using `$_` in a `foerach` loop is ... bad practice. that is intended for use in the _pipeline_, not in a `foreach` loop.

Comment: It's also not clear why you need a loop in your scenario, given that you only want to compare the values of a single property (hash-table entry).

Comment: The syntax error comes from broken use of [simplified syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_simplified_syntax): Your `Where` (`Where-Object`) call has no pipeline input. To refer to a property of the current pipeline input object, use just the property name (`foo`, not `$_.foo`), and it must be the _first_ operand. Even with these problems fixed your command wouldn't work, because you cannot use `-eq` to compare _whole arrays_.

Comment: does this mean that the result would only be: `2,4,6,8,10`?

Comment: Hopefully I should end up with $MyB with 2 propeties foo and bar.                      
$Myb.foo have to contain all numbers in $myB.foo (1 to 30) $MyB.bar should contain the numbers from $MyA.bar in the fist 10 entries.(where $MyA.foo match $MyB.foo) the rest should be set to zero.

Comment: Why not add to your question what is your expected result instead of in comments